# Cheapest transport to go to Istanbul from Van(Turkey)

Tags: public-transport, turkey

As I checked, flight tickets are not as cheap as flights between other Turk cities (for example, 16$ from Istanbul to Kayseri). So I'd like to know what other options are available. I did a quick Google search and bus tickets seemed pricy to me ([around 30 Euro](https://www.busradar.com/coach/istanbul/van/)). A short trip around 2 or 3 hours would be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

A cheaper trip from Istanbul to Van doesn't seem possible.

1. However Van is a selectable stop on TCDD (Turkish State Railways) [website](https://ebilet.tcddtasimacilik.gov.tr/), there is no train between Istanbul and Van.
2. Van is one of the furthest cities from Istanbul, so it is likely to be more expensive than Kayseri.

> - Istanbul-Kayseri:  611 km.
> - Istanbul-Van: 1295 km.

Comment: The problem with Turkish websites is that they don't recognize English as the international language.

Comment: @Gigili This is true. On the SE, I had to refer to pages in Turkish several times.